# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.navigate('Exercises', { exerciseName:ex})') React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have looked at similar questions but none of the solutions seem to be working for me and this has stumped me for 2 days now.

The error seems to be coming from passing this.props.navigate through to exerciseList.js however everything I have tried doesn't work. So any advice would be very much appreciated. The error occurs when I click through exerciseList.js to the individually rendered .

[Error message screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Mgy.jpg)

**Error Message:**

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.props.navigate('Exercises', { exerciseName:ex})')
```

**package.json**

```
    "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.2.3"
  },
```

**router.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    createAppContainer,
    createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
    createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import Home from '../home'
import ExercisePage from '../exercises/exercise';
import ExerciseList from '../exercise-list/exercise-list'
import CreateExerciseList from '../exercise-list/createListPage';

export const Route = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: { screen: Home },
        Exercises: { screen: ExercisePage },
        CreateList: { screen: CreateExerciseList },
        ExerciseList: { screen: ExerciseList },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home'
    }

);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Route);

export default AppContainer;
```

**home.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native';
import Record from './exercises/reps';
import ExerciseList from './exercise-list/exercise-list'
import ExerciseListItem from './exercise-list/exerciseListItem'
import CreateExerciseList from './exercise-list/createListPage';

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <CreateExerciseList navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate}/>

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**createListPage.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableNativeFeedback, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import ExerciseListItem from './exerciseListItem';

export default class CreateExerciseList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            workoutList: [
                {
                    "name": "Leg Day",
                    "exercises": [
                        "Benchpress",
                        "Squat",
                        "Lateral extensions",
                        "Bicep curls",
                        "Tricep extensions",
                        "Shrugs"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Arm Day",
                    "exercises": [
                        "Jumping Jacks",
                        "Hack squats",
                        "Tricep curls",
                        "Flying"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        const navigate = this.props.navigate

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>Create new list:</Text>
                </View>
                <View >
                    <Button style={styles.buttonNew} title='Create new list +'></Button>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.listContainer}>
                    {this.state.workoutList.map((workout) => {

                        return <TouchableNativeFeedback navigate={navigate} key={Date.now()} onPress={() => navigate('ExerciseList', {

                            title: workout.name,
                            exercises: workout.exercises,

                        })}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.listItem}>{workout.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableNativeFeedback>

                    })}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

**exerciseList.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import ExerciseListItem from './exerciseListItem'

export class ExerciseList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            exercises: []


        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        const title = navigation.getParam('title', 'no title available');
        const exercises = navigation.getParam('exercises', 'no exercises found');

        this.setState({
            title: title,
            exercises: exercises,

        })

    }


    render() {
        const navigate = this.props.navigate


        return (
            <View style={styles.scrollView}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.header}>{this.state.title}</Text>
                </View>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>

                    {this.state.exercises.map((ex) => {

                        return <ExerciseListItem style={styles.listItem} exerciseName={ex} key={Date.now()} onPress={(ex) => navigate('Exercises', {exerciseName: ex})} />
                    })}

                </ScrollView>
            </View>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you pass navigation through props you pass it as `navigation = {this.props.navigation}` (this is how you should do in home.js because you need the whole object not just the navigate function inside the object.). Another thing is that you don't need to pass navigation as props from home.js to createListPage.js because it's included as a screen in createStackNavigator.

Comment: @AtinSingh I have tried that but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Also not passing navigation as props from home.js to createListPage.js doesn't allow createListPage to have access to the navigate function.

Comment: Okay, then try passing the whole object as props. `navigation = {this.props.navigation}`. And then in createListPage destructure the navigation(if you want) `const {navigation} = this.props`. And then use navigation.navigate in button. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: @AtinSingh the error is occuring in the onPress of exercise-list.js not createListPage.js ..I tried passing this through createListPage down to exercise-list in the same way but I get the same error. It is weird because the same syntax is used in createListPage but doesn't work in exercise-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your exerciseList.js, try importing this:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
```

What `withNavigation` does is it provides the navigation prop directly to the component, without the need to pass it through props. You can read more about it here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Also, as Atin Singh mentioned on the comments, you should pass the navigation props like this: `navigation = {this.props.navigation}` and not as you are passing on your HOC. Then you'll just access the props on the child component like this: `this.props.navigation.`

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped!